# Moodle: enrolling an LDAP group of users

Tags: synchronization, ldap, moodle

I have managed to configured for the LDAP authentication and it is working properly.
And then when it comes to LDAP enrollment, I have encountered a problem.

Currently, I am testing with 2 courses, defined in LDAP. (Both of them do not exist on moodle at the very beginning.) I have managed to configured for the LDAP enrollment, and the 2 courses were created automatically after executing the synchronizing cron script. And the teaching role and student role were also synchronized successfully for `course2`.

Here is the schema for `course2`:

[image: LDAP schema for course2]

But then, when it comes to `course1`, an error occurred:

> == Synching course 'course1' for role 'student'
>
> Could not find user '{$a}', skipping

It should be because I was specifying the DN of a LDAP group (cn=026, ou=ou, ou=groups, dc=test) for `uniqueMember`, instead of giving the DN of individual users (e.g. as in `course2`: uid=7001, ou=users, dc=test), and it seemed like it could not recognize the difference and fail to search `cn=026` for the users.

Schema for `course1`:

[image: LDAP schema for course1]

Schema for `cn=026` group:

[image]

So, could anyone please tell me what could be the problems and how I should set up properly for this?

Thank you very much. I hope I have made myself clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

dn: cn=851,ou=moodle,ou=groups,dc=ldapserver,dc=tmcc,dc=edu
objectClass: moodleCourse
cn: 851
givenName: LV851
sn: 2007S/Introduction to Moodle
description: Jahr: 2007 Sommer,
 Announcement
teacherUid: userA
memberUid: user1

URL: http://moodle.mantrasoftindia.com 
Website: http://www.mantrasoftindia.com

Answer (score 0):

Go through following link to get each steps.

http://mantrasoftindia.wordpress.com/2014/04/28/steps-to-setup-authentication-and-enrolment-through-ldap-protocol/